# How to use same info window setup for more than one layer with identify, arcgis javascript api, cmv template

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer, identify

I am new to javascript and am playing around with customizing the CMV template https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app. I am trying to customize my info windows for my layers, and have had some luck modifying the identify.js file. I would like to use the same info window setup (fields and formatting) for more than one layer in my map service, but I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried to just add an array ([6,7]), and also tried adding a for loop to loop through the array with no luck. I don't get any errors, just no info windows load when I tried to use the array or loop through it:

```
msArray = [6,7];
for (var i = 0;  i < msArray.length; i++) {    define({map:!0,mapClickMode:!0,mapRightClickMenu:!0,identifyLayerInfos:!0,identifyTolerance:5,identifies:{
    mapSets:{msArray[i]:{title:"Map Sets",description: "<b>Name:</b>  {Sheet Label}<br><b>County:</b>  {County}<br><b>Route:</b>  {Route}<br><b>Postmile:</b>  {Postmile}<br><b>Map Type:</b>  {Map Type}\
    <br><b>Hanging File:</b>  {Hanging File}<br><b>Revision Date:</b>  {Revision Date}<br><b>Original Draft Decade:</b>  {Original Draft Decade}<br><b>Coordinate System:</b>  {Coordinate System} \
    <br><br><div align=center>{image_path}</div>"}};
}
```

Here's the code that works, when I reference one layer only (layer id in the code below is 6):

```
define({map:!0,mapClickMode:!0,mapRightClickMenu:!0,identifyLayerInfos:!0,identifyTolerance:5,identifies:{ 
mapSets:{6:{title:"Map Sets",description: "<b>Name:</b>  {Sheet Label}<br><b>County:</b>  {County}<br><b>Route:</b>  {Route}<br><b>Postmile:</b>  {Postmile}<br><b>Map Type:</b>  {Map Type}\
<br><b>Hanging File:</b>  {Hanging File}<br><b>Revision Date:</b>  {Revision Date}<br><b>Original Draft Decade:</b>  {Original Draft Decade}<br><b>Coordinate System:</b>  {Coordinate System} \
<br><br><div align=center>{image_path}</div>"}},
```

UPDATE: Latest code posted below, using function provided in solution. Second function does not work:

```
define(function () {

    function createSharedTemplateMS () {
        return {
            title:"Map Sets",
            description: [
                '<b>Name:</b>  {Sheet Label}<br>',
                '<b>County:</b>  {County}<br>',
                '<b>Route:</b>  {Route}<br>',
                '<b>Postmile:</b>  {Postmile}<br>',
                '<b>Map Type:</b>  {Map Type} <br>',
                '<b>Hanging File:</b>  {Hanging File}<br>',
                '<b>Revision Date:</b>  {Revision Date}<br>',
                '<b>Original Draft Decade:</b>  {Original Draft Decade}<br>',
                '<b>Coordinate System:</b>  {Coordinate System}<br><br>',
                '<div align=center>{image_path}</div>'
            ].join('')
         };
    }
    return {
        map:true,
        mapClickMode:true,
        mapRightClickMenu:true,
        identifyLayerInfos:true,
        identifyTolerance:5,
        identifies: {
            mapSets: {
                6: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                7: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                8: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                9: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                10: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                11: createSharedTemplateMS(),
                12: createSharedTemplateMS()
            }
        }
    };
});

define(function () {

    function createSharedTemplatePrcl () {
        return {
            title:"Parcels",
            description: [
                '<b>Name:</b>  {Name}<br>',
                '<b>County:</b>  {County}<br>',
                '<b>Route:</b>  {Route}<br>',
                '<b>Postmile:</b>  {Postmile}',
                '<br><b>Description:</b>  {Description}<br>',
                '<b>Area:</b>  {Area}<br>',
                '<b>Map Sheet:</b>  {Map Sheet}<br>',
                '<b>Parcel Type:</b>  {Parcel Type}<br>',
                '<b>Parcel Phase:</b>  {Parcel Phase}',
                '<br><b>Geometry Quality:</b>  {Geometry Quality}<br>',
                '<b>Source:</b>  {Source}<br><br>',
                '<br><div align=center>{doc_path}</div>'
            ].join('')
         };
    }
    return {
        map:true,
        mapClickMode:true,
        mapRightClickMenu:true,
        identifyLayerInfos:true,
        identifyTolerance:5,
        identifies: {
            mapSets: {
                1: createSharedTemplatePrcl(),
                2: createSharedTemplatePrcl(),
                3: createSharedTemplatePrcl(),
                4: createSharedTemplatePrcl()
            }
        }   
    };
});
```

Comment: Is this code for a single file? You can't combine them like that. Put the two functions side-by-side in the code I provided and combine your mapSets into a single object with sublayers 1 - 12 all in the same place.

Comment: Yes I have the code in the same file - I'm not sure exactly what you mean by side by side?

Comment: I can't post the whole code here due to stackexchange limits on comment size. Here is your code reworked into something functional: http://pastebin.com/uCs0U8i7

Comment: I'm trying to use one of the templates now for a feature layer also, but it won't work and I'm not sure why - it loads all fields in the info window for the feature service without the formatting. Or must I use a separate function?

Comment: You should be able to use the same function for a feature layer. I believe you have found a bug that will be fixed in release 1.3.1 (due today or tomorrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when working with CMV, you should start with the unminified versions of the configuration files that will make it much easier to work with. The latest release is [here](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/releases/tag/v1.3.0).

With respect to your question, you can use a function to create the popup template. Here's an reformatted example of your code reusing the same template for 3 different sublayers - 2 for your `mapSets` layer and one for another layer. Obviously, you'll need to modify it for the layers in your CMV application.

```
define(function () {

    function createSharedTemplate () {
        return {
            title:"Map Sets",
            description: [
                '<b>Name:</b>  {Sheet Label}<br>',
                '<b>County:</b>  {County}<br>',
                '<b>Route:</b>  {Route}<br>',
                '<b>Postmile:</b>  {Postmile}<br>',
                '<b>Map Type:</b>  {Map Type} <br>',
                '<b>Hanging File:</b>  {Hanging File}<br>',
                '<b>Revision Date:</b>  {Revision Date}<br>',
                '<b>Original Draft Decade:</b>  {Original Draft Decade}<br>',
                '<b>Coordinate System:</b>  {Coordinate System} align=center>{image_path}'
            ].join('')
         };
    }

    return {
        map:true,
        mapClickMode:true,
        mapRightClickMenu:true,
        identifyLayerInfos:true,
        identifyTolerance:5,
        identifies: {
            mapSets: {
                6: createSharedTemplate(),
                7: createSharedTemplate()
            },
            layer2: {
                1: createSharedTemplate()
            }
        }
    };
});
```

One last thing, I used a trick of putting all the text for the description into multiple elements of an array. I find this easier to see each line of the HTML in the code. When doing that, it became obvious that you had an extra closing div tag `</div>` at the end of your code. I think that would explain the CSS problem I assisted you with on IRC.

Comment: thanks so much for the response this is very helpful! i have a ways to go in learning javascript

Comment: this works great. I tried to create another function in the same js file that defines a popup for several other layers, but it doesn't work. I basically copied and pasted the above function below itself, then changed the function name and parameters. Not sure why it doesnt work

Comment: can you post your current code?

Comment: posted code above

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with CMV, there are a few JavaScript mistakes in your code if that's the exact code you're using.

Firstly, you cannot use a variable (`myArray[i]`) as a name for JSON object key. Please see [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) and [this reference](http://json.org). You should've gotten an error for this, I would've guessed...

Secondly, you cannot put Dojo's `define` in a loop. You should only call define once per file.

Lastly, I believe you need to explicitly specify each layer you want to identify with specific fields you need. CMV documented as such:

```
// config object definition:
//  {<layer id>:{
//      <sub layer number>:{
//          <pop-up definition, see link below>
//          }
//      },
//  <layer id>:{
//      <sub layer number>:{
//          <pop-up definition, see link below>
//          }
//      }
//  }

// for details on pop-up definition see: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_popuptemplate.html
```

Familiarizing yourself better with JavaScript and Dojo basics will help you a lot in the long run when creating applications with ArcGIS JSAPI

As a side note, please format your code better in the question, we are not machines and cannot read compressed code very readily :)

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply and tips. I tihnk it was not helping that the code I initially downloaded was not foramtted to begin with.